# Log on to Project Server and call PSI method

Tags: authentication, project-server-2007, psi

I have a Microsoft Project Server 2007 instance on a network server. I want to call from a development machine a webservice from PSI. How can I connect to PS by specifying a username and password? (Something similar to what happens when you access the PWA in a browser, you enter your username and password, even if on the computer from which you work you have another user/password).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, I simply set the credentials for the web service to network credentials using a custom user, domain and password. Seems to work for what I need.

```
myPSWebService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass", "domain");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Project Server's provided impersonation solution. There is a How To and Walkthrough [available here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa974347(v=office.12).aspx).

From memory it's quite involved to get working (e.g. need to generate web service proxies) but once you do it works well.

Comment: Instead, I simply set the credentials for the web service to NetworkCredentials using a custom user, domain and password. Seems to work for what I need.